# Karpathy's code training neural net to play Pong using Policy Gradients

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I'm looking at Andrej Karpathy's "Training a Neural Network ATARI Pong agent with Policy Gradients from raw pixels" https://gist.github.com/karpathy/a4166c7fe253700972fcbc77e4ea32c5 . I'm not a Python person so I'm trying to write this code in Matlab. I have 2 questions.

Question 1: I noticed that `xs`, `hs`, `dlogps`, and `drs` are initialized to `[],[],[],[]` (line 67) and reset to `[],[],[],[]` after each episode (line 103). But `epx`, `eph`, `epdlogp`, and `epr` are neither initialized nor reset. They seem to keep growing forever (lines 99-102). Am I correct? I'm not familiar with the nuances of `np.vstack`.

Question 2: If I had a game with player movement options up, down, right, and left, how would I need to modify this code to make it work (beside the obvious modification to 4 nodes in the output layer)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're imagining nuances of `numpy.vstack` that it [doesn't have](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html). Lines 99-102 of the code you linked to **assign the result of the** `vstack` **function to the variables concerned.** Any previous values of these variables will be replaced.

```
epx = np.vstack(xs)
eph = np.vstack(hs)
epdlogp = np.vstack(dlogps)
epr = np.vstack(drs)
```

For the second part of your question I think you need to try something out, and ask a new question showing what you've tried if it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks. So is epx = np.vstack(xs) the way (or a way) for Python to say epx = xs?

Comment: Eh? No. Looking at the code, `xs` is a Python list of numpy vectors, and `np.vstack(xs)` reshapes it into one 2-D numpy array. I think you need to step through this code in a Python IDE and examine what's going on before you try and rewrite it in MATLAB. Or at least, try out the numpy operations at the Python prompt so you understand what they do.